# CSS3 animations only work on page refresh in IE 11

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-11, transition

A site I have taken over is using CSS3 animations to power the slider.

They seem to work fine across Chrome/Safari/Firefox but for some reason in IE11 they will not load when you initially hit the page for the first time.

Once you're on the page if you refresh or open chrome dev tools then they it work as they should (bar the last one which gets stuck?).

[SITE HERE >>](http://creatrixtest.com/thp-dev/)

[VIDEO EXAMPLE >>](http://creatrix.tinytake.com/sf/MTYxNDk3XzEwMTUyMDE)

After browsing a few related articles i've moved the keyframes to the top of my css sheet but it hasn't seemed to of made any difference.

Can anybody tell me what i'm missing?

```
#slide0 {
    background-image:url('../../img/auto-enrol-slide.png'); 
    background-position: left bottom -600px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#6CA1C1;
}
#slide0.animate {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.85s;
   -webkit-animation-name: backgroundUp2;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
   -moz-animation-duration: 0.85s;
   -moz-animation-name: backgroundUp2;
   -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -o-animation-delay: 0s;
   -o-animation-duration: 0.85s;
   -o-animation-name: backgroundUp2;
   -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-delay: 0s;
   animation-duration: 0.85s;
   animation-name: backgroundUp2;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% {background-position: left bottom -600px; }
    100% {background-position: left bottom -100px; } 
}

@-moz-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% { background-position: left bottom -600px; }
    100% { background-position: left bottom -100px; } 
}

@-ms-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% { background-position: left bottom -600px; }
    100% {background-position: left bottom -100px; } 
}

@keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% {background-position: left bottom -600px; }
    100% {background-position: left bottom -100px; } 
}
```

[FULL STYLESHEET >>](http://creatrixtest.com/thp-dev/wp-content/themes/theme/css/build/base.css?v=2)

Comment: This is what i'm getting: http://creatrix.tinytake.com/sf/MTYxNDk3XzEwMTUyMDE Are you on windows 7?

Comment: I am on windows 8. I see what your problem is. For me, the lady comes up without refreshing. Can you run IE once without addons and also tell me the  IE version( LONG ONE) by navigating to About Internet Explorer?

Comment: It's version: 11.0.9600.17801

Comment: mine is a little older the last segment being 17728. Did you try without addons?

Comment: Just tried it in IE (No Add Ons) three times and it worked once but then not for the following two times. Strange how the other items animate fine though?

Comment: I tried it about 20 times and faced the issue once. I am not sure if it's the time taken by the image to load.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may stumble across this, I got it to work - I changed the values in the parameters to all pixel units.

Seems like IE doesn't like it when you mix and match the property values.

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% {background-position: 0 360px ; }
    100% {background-position: 0 -50px; } 
}

@-moz-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% { background-position: 0 360px ; }
    100% { background-position: 0 -50px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% { background-position: 0 360px ; }
    100% {background-position:0 -50px; } 
}

@keyframes backgroundUp2 {
    0% {background-position: 0 360px ; }
    100% {background-position:0 -50px; } 
}

#slide0 {
    background-image:url('../../img/auto-enrol-slide.png'); 
    background-position-x:0;
    background-position-y:360px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #6CA1C1;
}
```